# Spring Boot 2 + Webjars + Bootstrap + Thymeleaf = themes not applied

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-4, webjars

I was exploring a little Spring Boot, and I was having a look at some frontend libraries - which I admit I have almost never seen :)

I am probably doing some stupid mistake that makes Bootstrap not working. I am trying to set up a header page.
As I hate doing simple things, I am using Spring Boot, Webjars and Thymeleaf. All for the first time. But it seems everything is all right, and I cannot understand what is wrong.

First of all, here is the Gradle dependencies. I am using spring 2.0.0.M7. I cut the applied plugins repositories and group/version

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: "${springBootVersion}"
    }
}


// ##### COMPILE DEPENDENCIES
// DATABASE
compile     group: 'mysql',                     name: 'mysql-connector-java'

// SPRING
compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',  name: 'spring-boot-devtools'
compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',  name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',  name: 'spring-boot-starter-json'
compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',  name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
compile     group: 'org.springframework.boot',  name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'

// THYMELEAF
compile     group: 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf',   name: 'thymeleaf-layout-dialect',  version: '2.2.2'

// WEB JAVASCRIPT LIBS
compile     group: 'org.webjars',               name: 'webjars-locator',  version: '0.32-1'
compile     group: 'org.webjars',               name: 'bootstrap',        version: '4.0.0-beta.3'
```

I am using webjars locator. I liked this approach because I have complete control of my libraries here, and I do not have to put version numbers on the application.

I have then set up the resource handler to retrieve the webjars, and the spring layout dialect...

```
@Bean
WebMvcConfigurer configurer() {
   return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
          registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webjars/")
                 .resourceChain(false);
      }
   };
}

@Bean
LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
   return new LayoutDialect();
}
```

... the Spring application...

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "it.aegidea.wolf" })
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

... the controller...

```
@Controller
public class HomepageController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getHomepage() {
      return "homepage";
   }

}
```

... the overall layout...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <!--/*  Each token will be replaced by their respective titles in the resulting page. */-->
    <title layout:title-pattern="$LAYOUT_TITLE - $CONTENT_TITLE">Task List</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


</head>
<body>

    <div th:include="commons/header :: page-header"></div>

    <div class="container">
        <div layout:fragment="content">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Injected -->
    <script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/webjars/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

... the header...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" th:fragment="page-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#title-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="title-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

... and finally, the homepage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html
        lang="en"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
        layout:decorate="~{commons/layout}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Wolf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content">
            <p th:text="'Hello World!'" >Hello World!</p>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">This is a success button</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">This is a warning button</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">This is a danger button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The (weird) effect is that style get correctly applied to the buttons in the homepage, but not to the navbar.

What I've tried to do is

- trying to include bootstrap, popper and jquery with direct links (taken from Bootstrap homepage)

  - trying to directly include the header into the homepage, just after

I am 100% sure I am doing some incredibly stupid mistake, but I've probably seen the code so many times that I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for anyone's help :)

Lorenzo

Comment: can you upload your full repo to github?

Comment: @chenrui thanks :)
https://github.com/il-lore/tmp_wolf.git

Comment: just FYI, I started adding some hibernate user table and spring security stuff, so things might be slightly different from the code I've posted

Answer (score 1):

As expected, the answer is always simpler than expected.
I was using bootstrap 3 css classes (navbar-fixed-top) with bootstrap 4, which has changed the classes.

Example header for bootstrap 4:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

Example menu item:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</li>
```

Here is a guide for bootstrap 4

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/